# If $x$ divides $x-z$, then $x$ divides $z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> For any integer x and z , if $x|(x-z)$ then $x|z$

My attempt: suppose $x|(x-z),$ let $y= x-z$

$x|y $  means there is any integer r such that $y=r*x$

So $ x-z=rx $, which equals $(x-z)/(x) =r $  this is where I get stuck.

Comment: im unsure what tag to use

Answer (score 0):

You con write:
$$\frac {x-z}{x}=k$$ with $k$ integer. This expression si equivalent: $$\frac {x}{x}-\frac {z}{x}=k$$ but you can continue  $$1-\frac {z}{x}=k$$ $k$ is integer therefore $x|z$

Comment: see I was thinking that; however, I figured it was wrong because of the 1- in front of the z/x